# Set Value to 0 if Cell Value is 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I have found here and modified to my needs that finds a match in the first column and replaces the second column with new values if a match is found.  It works unless the value in the second column is 0.  If the value in the second column is 0, then no change takes place.  Here is the script.

```
    function adjustment() {
  
  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[5];

  //destination spreadsheet
  var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
  var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheets()[8]; 

  var values = srcSheet.getRange("C22:C23").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
destSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = destSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })

var statusValue = srcSheet.getRange("C22:C23").getValue();   //added

if (statusValue != '') {                       //added
destSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).setValues([data]);   //added

srcSheet.getRange("C22:C23").clearContent()
}
}
```

Not sure what I need to change to make this happen.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Just to clarify since I was not quite sure what you were saying in your answer`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From your posted question, I guessed that you might have wanted to keep the value of 0 of column "B". But, from your reply, I understood that my understanding was not correct. I think that this is due to my very very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: And, unfortunately, from `I will give an example. To begin with, say Column A has the value "apples" in one cell, and the corresponding row in Column B has the value "20". IF we run out of apples, we want to replace the "20" with "0" with a script. However, with the current script, "20" is not getting replaced. The cell value remains "20".`, I cannot understand what you want to do.

Comment: And, I noticed that a user who could understand the expected result of your reply has already posted an answer. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful. So, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my very very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill, again. I would like to study English more.

Comment: Thank you @Tainake.  You have been helpful with other issues before.  Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the script reads the 0 value as an empty string and therefore the condition is not met here:

```js
return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
```

What you can do instead is to get the display values instead of the cell values.

What I propose is:

#### Instead of:

```js
var values = srcSheet.getRange("C22:C23").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
  });
```

#### You can try:

```js
  var values = srcSheet.getRange("C22:C23").getDisplayValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
  });
```

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Perfect.  I figured it had something to do with that, but did not know the correct function to call.  This was very helpful!